# Custom styled scrollbar for overflow areas using CSS

Tags: css, scrollbar

What is the most effective way to have scrollbars on a website to a custom style using CSS?

I'm talking about scrollbars within a DIV with overflow: scroll; set and not on the browser window maybe using a JPG as the scrollbar design.

Hope this explains what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scrollbar is a component of the OS, so the browser doesn't give you any liberty for styling it. The best alternative is using Javascript, there are some good libraries for custom scrollbars, [Tiny Scrollbar](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/), for example.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you can redraw scrollbars with pure CSS only on webkit browsers:

- http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

For other browsers you've to use workarounds, using javascript to emulate the scrolling effect. Some resources:

- http://slodive.com/web-development/jquery-scroll/
- http://www.noupe.com/javascript/30-javascriptajax-techniques-for-sliders-scrollers-and-scrollbars.html
- http://www.script-tutorials.com/custom-scrollbars-cross-browser-solution/
- http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/jquerycustomscrollbar/index.htm